# How to use CSS calc according to a certain amount of li's?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am making a website that the nav items could change around a lot. What I wanted to do is JavaScript or something like that to pick up the amount of nav items I have, send that to my CSS file and divide the width of the nav by the amount of items then assign it to the width of the .head li. If anyone can help that would be amazing!

Regards, Jayden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with pure/native CSS. So, I can see two workarounds for your problem:

1. You can use the [Less Framework](http://lesscss.org/)
2. Other way, you'll need to use Javascript to do that, for example:

   - HTML

     ```
     <ul id="myList">
         <li>My Nav 1</li>
         <li>My Nav 2</li>
         <li>My Nav 3</li>
         <!-- My Nav (...) N -->
     </ul>
     ```
   - Javascript / jQuery

     ```
     $(function() {
         var myFullWidth = 600; // define your full width
         var lis = $("ul#myList li");
         lis.css("width", parseInt(myFullWidth / lis.length, 10).toString() + "px");
     });
     ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter the CSS file, but you can alter the CSS on page with javascript.

This is a simple Jquery example where the margin-top is the amount of li elements times two.

Html:

```
<button>Add item</button>
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var itemCount = $('ul').children().length;
$('button').click(function(){
    $('ul').append('<li>Item</li>');
    itemCount = itemCount = $('ul').children().length;
    $('ul').css('margin-top', itemCount * 2);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q36u2/

Comment: Hi Whitebird, Sorry for the late reply. Could you please be a bit more specific as the code you have given me does not work, by looking at it I thought it would. Do I need to do anything in CSS?

Comment: In your CSS file you define your starting state. With this script you adjust that starting state. When setting the width of the element in javascript with `$('element').css('width', amount)` you override the default state.